# How to remove particular element in angularjs if its in json data?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am using angular js and ionic framework.A problem is i need to remove a element from the jsondata which comes from API.

Json data :

```
 [["abcd@gmail.com","joe"],["xyz@gmail.com","brain"],["hhh@gmail.com","bob"]];
```

i need to remove 2nd element "xyz@gmail.com" and dislay only the remaining elements

```
  [["abcd@gmail.com","joe"],["hhh@gmail.com","bob"]];
```

Controller condition:

```
   if(response.RETURN == "TRUE") {                   
        var listObject = JSON.parse(response.LIST); 
        $scope.ulist = listObject; 
     //HERE I NEED TO FILTER THAT  PARTICULAR ELEMENT 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a `for` loop will do it, right?

```
$scope.ulist = [];
for (var i = 0, len = listObject.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if(listObject[i][0] != "xyz@gmail.com") {
        $scope.ulist.push(listObject[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `Array.filter`:

```
$scope.ulist = listObject.filter(function (email) {
     return email[0] !== "xyz@gmail.com";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is using splice method of Javascript.

```
if(response.RETURN == "TRUE") {                   
    var listObject = JSON.parse(response.LIST); 
    listObject.splice(1,1); 
    $scope.ulist = listObject.; 
 //HERE I NEED TO FILTER THAT  PARTICULAR ELEMENT 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to handle this is to use lodash library, it will save your time and make your code readable.

```
_.pullAt(array, [indexes])
```

Removes elements from array corresponding to the given indexes and returns an array of the removed elements. Indexes may be specified as an array of indexes or as individual arguments.

```
 var array = [5, 10, 15, 20];
    var evens = _.pullAt(array, 1, 3);

    console.log(array);
    // → [5, 15]
    console.log(evens);
    // → [10, 20]
```

and in your case:

```
var listOfFilteresObjects = _.pullAt(listOfObjects,2);
```

and thats all bro,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
   var testArr = [["abcd@gmail.com", "joe"],
                  ["xyz@gmail.com", "brain"],
                  ["hhh@gmail.com", "bob"]];

   var customFilter = function(arr, filterStr) {
       var result = [];
       angular.forEach(arr, function (a1) {
           var tmp = a1;
           var idx = 0;
           angular.forEach(tmp, function (a2) {
               if ((a2 !== filterStr)
               && (idx === 0)) {
                   result.push(tmp);
               }
               idx++;
           });
       });
       return result;
   }

   var filteredTestArr = customFilter(testArr, "xyz@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.